# Regex to match a rather complex string

Tags: javascript, regex

Any experts on Regex, that could potentially find a pattern on this data, im looking for one that will match exactly, down to spaces and commas and dashes. Here is the sample data of what i need to match:

---

word word, alphanumeric-PRT-word-number

word word, alphanumeric-PRT-number

---

-word: any size word

-alphanumeric: 3 letters and up to 2 numbers, so XXX# or XXX##

-number: up to 3 digits, so # or ## or ###

-PRT: is the only static value here

NOTE: no other punctuation other than the spaces, comma and dashes where they are.

---

So far have something close to it but rather clunky and it doesnt cover all bases, i built it here: http://buildregex.com/ using their logic and it kinda works:

```
/(?:[^_\ ]+)(?:\ )(?:[^_\ ]+), (?:[^_\ ]+)-PRT-(?:[^_\ ]*)/gi
```

If any can assist in refining this that will be welcome

https://regex101.com/r/8cc52u/2

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need experts but [*What does this regex mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: What is a word for you? Only letters from `[a-zA-Z]` or with diacritics `éèçàÉÀÖù...`? Are dash allowed? or apostroph?

Comment: @revo although rather usefull as reference...the data there is cumbersome for begginers. I totally agree with the givethecodez issue...but not everyone is looking for that. I had attempted kn my own before and now thanks to the answer i was able to piece together some of the concepts to do other regex expressions. Thanks for assisting there too i saw your remarks on the slected answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
/^[a-z]+\s[a-z]+,\s[a-z]{3}\d{1,2}-prt-([a-z]+-){0,1}\d{1,3}$/gi
```

- `^`: start of line
- `[a-z]+`: one or more letters
- `\s`: any space character
- `[a-z]+`: one or more letters
- `,`: ,
- `\s`: any space character
- `[a-z]{3}`: three letters
- `\d{1,2}`: one or two digits
- `-prt-`: -prt-
- `([a-z]+-){0,1}`: one or more letters followed by -, zero or one time
- `\d{1,3}`: one, two or three digits
- `$`: end of line

Example: https://regex101.com/r/BhS8kM/5

Or, as [suggested by revo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963027/regex-to-match-a-rather-complex-string/44963451?noredirect=1#comment76902584_44963451):

```
/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+, [a-z]{3}\d{1,2}-prt-([a-z]+-)?\d{1,3}$/gi
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/BhS8kM/7

Comment: This also matches `word word, wrd12-prt--5`

Comment: @revo Nice catch, thanks! I've updated answer to cover that scenario.

Comment: GJ FYI all `{0,1}` range could be converted to `?` which has same meaning. I believe also `\s` isn't suitable as being not strict in catching [Space 0x20](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm). Use space character alone.

Comment: Thats simply genius no only that your explanation help me understand and do another comple regex...grateful forever. :)